# How to Parse XML with JSON Output in Swift ios?

Tags: ios, json, xml, swift, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse the output of a soap api.

```
<string xmlns="webservices.fmx.bz/">
{ "ui": [ { "t": "1234", "vid": "123", "cn": "Company Name" } ] }
</string>
```

i have been parseing it manually

```
  var responseString = response.result.value?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r\n", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<string xmlns=\"webservices.fmx.bz/\">", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</string>", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "{  ui: [    {      ", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "}  ]}", withString: "")
            responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( "  ", withString: " ")
            var myStringArr = responseString?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
            var companyNameStr = myStringArr![2].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("cn:", withString: "")
            companyNameStr = companyNameStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&amp;", withString: "&")
            companyNameStr = companyNameStr.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(companyNameStr, forKey: "companyName")
```

Anyone know a simplier solution or library I can use ?

Comment: heres an easy and straight forward way for nsxmlparser -- [**Link**](http://dubinski.org/wpis/easy-xml-parsing-in-swift/)

Comment: This is NOT the way to do it @Rayen. Please use an inbuilt parser.

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to do it...
Had to clean up the data string then convert back to nsdata

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, emconOWO, parameters: params) .responseString { response in
        print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
//            print(response.result.value)

        var responseString = response.result.value?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r\n", withString: "")
        responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<string xmlns=\"webservices.fmx.bz/\">", withString: "")
        responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", withString: "")
        responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</string>", withString: "")
     responseString = responseString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")

        print(responseString)

  let data = responseString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS provides an inbuilt JSON parser which parses the JSON string completely and builds a dictionary which represents the JSON structure.

However, iOS does NOT provide a similar approach for XML. The NSXMLParser provided by iOS parses using an "event-driven" model. ie: The parser notifies a delegate of events and it's our job to build up a structure depending on the elements.

The JSON approach is relatively easier as we can simply query the parsed data structure for the objects we need.

However, I found that there is a library which performs a similar activity for an XML in Swift. You can find it [here](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash).

Please check it and you should be able to parse the XML and build a parsed object with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var parser:XMLParser?
    var foundChars: String = ""
    var personsStr: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseXML()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func parseXML() {
        let str: NSString = "<Data><Persons>[{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"Catagory 1\"},{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"Catagory 2\"}]</Persons><class>[{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"WEAVING\"}]</class></Data>"
        if let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            parser = XMLParser.init(data: data)
            parser!.delegate = self
            parser!.parse()
        }

    }
}
extension ViewController: XMLParserDelegate {
    public func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        debugPrint("Person str is:: " + self.personsStr)
        //TODO: You have to build your json object from the PersonStr now
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        self.foundChars = self.foundChars + string
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        debugPrint("end element::" + elementName)
        if (elementName == "Persons") {
            self.personsStr = self.foundChars
        }
        self.foundChars = ""
    }
}
```